# Array not displaying, Notice: array to string conversion

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am attempting to display the contents of an array. I have a `SELECT` query that transfers two rows from the data base with a `WHERE` statement;

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$inspectit = array();
$update1 = $_POST['inspect'];
$query1 = "SELECT title, reason FROM daysoff WHERE DATE(start) = '$update1' AND gighold     = 1";
$day = mysql_query($query1); 
while($requesting = mysql_fetch_array($day)) {                           
$inspectit[] = $requesting;
}
$_SESSION['inspect'] = $inspectit; 
header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ;
?>
```

I place the session variable into a new variable,`$inspect`, defined on a different page. I then try to display the array using;

```
<?php
session_start();
$inspect = $_SESSION['inspect'];
if($inspect == true) {
echo " </br>Name: </br><a> ". implode($inspect) ."</a></br></br>";
unset ($_SESSION['inspect']);
} 
?>
```

If i `var_dump($inspect)` all the expected data is there, but it looks like an array holding another array. If i execute code as shown above, this gives a notice of array to string conversion. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Buddy Try `if($inspect)` instead of `if($inspect == true)`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all above methods to no avail. I did however get it to work by doing;

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
$inspectname = array();
$inspectreason = array();
$update1 = $_POST['inspect'];
$query1 = "SELECT title, reason FROM daysoff WHERE DATE(start) = '$update1' AND gighold = 1";
$day = mysql_query($query1); 
while($requesting = mysql_fetch_array($day)) {                           
$inspectname[] = $requesting['title'];
$inspectreason[] = $requesting['reason'];
}
$_SESSION['inspectname'] = $inspectname; 
$_SESSION['inspectreason'] = $inspectreason; 
header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ;
?>
```

then to call and display the arrays;

```
<?php
if($inspectname == true) {
$size = sizeof($inspectname) - 1;
for($count = 0; $count <= $size; $count++){
echo " </br>Name: </br><a> ". $inspectname[$count] ."</a>";
echo " </br>Details: </br><a> ". $inspectreason[$count] ."</a></br></br>";
unset ($_SESSION['inspectname']);
unset ($_SESSION['inspectreason']);}
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $inspect = $_SESSION['inspect'];
    if($inspect) {
        echo " </br>Name: </br><a> ". implode($inspect) ."</a></br></br>";
        unset ($_SESSION['inspect']);
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an array of query result into an array. try to change:

from:

```
while($requesting = mysql_fetch_array($day)) {    
    $inspectit[] = $requesting;                     
}
```

to:

```
$inspectit = mysql_fetch_array($day);
```

Comment: i have tried this but the only data inside `$inspectit` is the last entry to fit the `SELECT` query?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION['inspect']` is an array, so you can used check like

```
$inspect = $_SESSION['inspect'];
if(count($inspect)>0) {
```

instead of

```
if($inspect == true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $inspect = $_SESSION['inspect'];
  if($inspect) {
    echo " </br>Name: </br><a> ". implode("-",$inspect) ."</a></br></br>";
    unset ($_SESSION['inspect']);
  } 
 ?>
```

or you can use `empty()` function too like

```
 <?php
  session_start();
  $inspect = $_SESSION['inspect'];
  if(!empty($inspect)) {
    echo " </br>Name: </br><a> ". implode("-",$inspect) ."</a></br></br>";
    unset ($_SESSION['inspect']);
  } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `$inspectit = array();` you are setting $inspectit to an array, then you are trying to set the string (or non-array) `$_SESSION['inspect']` to equal that array. You can iterate multiple `$_SESSION` variables to each iteration of `$inspectit` as follows:

```
$n=0;
while($requesting = mysql_fetch_array($day)) {                           
 $_SESSION['inspect'+$n] = $requesting;
 $n++;
}
$_SESSION['inpect_count']=$n;
```

Thus you will know how many variables you setup with the `$_SESSION['inpect_count']`